# Vue 3 Composition API unit test : $route is undefined in onMounted() hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

I have a `onMounted()` hook in my component `setup()` function which access the `$route.params property`, but when I mock the `$route` object in my test, `$route` is `undefined` in the `onMounted()` hook, hence throwing an error. Here's the code

**Component.vue :**

```
<template>
  <div>{{ this.$route.params.id }}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, onMounted} from 'vue'
import {useRoute} from "vue-router";

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Component',
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute()
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(route.params.id)
    })

    return {}
  }
})
</script>
```

**Component.spec.ts :**

```
import {mount} from "@vue/test-utils";
import Component from "@/views/Bundle/Component.vue";

test('test description', async () => {
  const mockRoute = {
    params: {
      id: 1
    }
  }
  const mockRouter = {
    push: jest.fn()
  }

  const wrapper = mount(Component, {
    global: {
      mocks: {
        $route: mockRoute,
        $router: mockRouter
      }
    }
  })

  await wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')
})
```

**Error thrown:**
TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

I'm using version 2.0.0-rc.12 of vue-test-utils.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the mount options (and therefore the mocks for $route & $router) are not taken into consideration when using composition API.

When you e.g. take a look at the `matched` property of the route (in the component), the array will be empty since there are no routes matched and no routes available in the context in general. But they updated the docs and you will see an example there.

No idea for a non-imperative way of mocking this per test though...

[Using a mocked router with Composition API](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/vue-router.html#using-a-mocked-router-with-composition-api)